# Encoding lemmas for use in Affinity Propagation/Finding natural clusters in text data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a dataframe that several columns of lemmatized text (multiple paragraphs worth of text per row - not categorical), plus some other int, datetime, and float columns.
I'd like to use the text for Affinity Propagation, to find clusters within the data. sklearn.cluster.affinitypropagation doesn't work with text data though and returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-110-41dbca660b33> in <module>()
----> 1 f = clusterer.fit(TIP_with_rats_nlp)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\cluster\affinity_propagation_.py in fit(self, X, y)
    289             similarities / affinities.
    290         """
--> 291         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    292         if self.affinity == "precomputed":
    293             self.affinity_matrix_ = X

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    415         # make sure we actually converted to numeric:
    416         if dtype_numeric and array.dtype.kind == "O":
--> 417             array = array.astype(np.float64)
    418         if not allow_nd and array.ndim >= 3:
    419             raise ValueError("Found array with dim %d. %s expected <= 2."

ValueError: could not convert string to float: "main area improvement plan specifically have ahead time want work break unit daily learning target goal week ahead detailed weekly overview activity lesson align learning target make sure lesson opportunity student intellectually engage historical material.1 deadline planning 's week learn target write document 7 pm fill remain weekly overview template 2 plan google document share co teacher order feedback 3 weekly meeting mentor work create week learn target 4 observe structure classroom co teaching style observe rigor bring classroom step 1 -3 start 9/26/14 continue year step 4 start 9/29/14 work observe teacher week work close work imporvement especially help break planning create idea daily lesson look google document planning improve class observation"
```

What's the best way to convert this text data to something cluster.affinitypropagation can work with? 
If Affinity Propogation even the best options for this? I've looked into kNN, but I specifically want something where I don't have to pre-select the number of groups and this seemed like the best option.

I've looked into sklearn.preprocessing.labelencoder but that seems to only work with single strings/categorical data. I've found similar questions with solutions like:

```
def encode(col):
    unq = {}
    count=0
    for item in col:
        if item not in unq:
            unq[item] = count
            count += 1
    enc = [unq[item] for item in col]
    return enc,unq
```

But that doesn't take into account each individual word in the list and merely assigns an ever increasing numeric identifier to each row.

Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: All scikit estimators work only with numerical data. So you need to convert your text to some numerical form by pre-processing it.

Comment: @VivekKumar - yes, my question is about how best to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure your level of understanding, so I'm going to try to be pretty verbose.

Check out the `from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer`

TFIDF stands for Term Frequency Inverse Document Frequency.  (A bit of a misnomer, I might have chosen Term Frequency Inverse Corpus Frequency).  Basically, how often a word appears in a document vs. how often it appears in the corpus (collection of all documents you're working with).  This will leave you with a matrix where each row is a document, and each column represents a word in your corpus's vocabulary.  The value of each cell represents the TFIDF for that term.  This could leave you with a matrix with 10,000+ columns, so you might want to do some dimensionality reduction.  Generally reducing to 200-300 dimensions works well with Natural Language Processing (NLP).

I don't know much about Afinity Propogation, the two forms of clustering I'm familiar with are K-means and Hierarchical Clustering.  Curious why you chose Affinity Propagation.  Would you be interested in chatting about this?  I'd be more than happy to be a resource for you on this project, I have nothing to do at work right now.

Comment: Affinity Propagation seemed like the best option considering I'm specifically looking to avoid pre-setting the number of clusters (which it seemed like you have to do with kNN and other similar clustering techniques).  This is my first big NLP project and I've used TF-IDF for topic modeling but again with that you have to specify the number of "topics".  Would love to have someone to chat with about this project, as I think I'm in over my head.

Comment: Do you know how stackoverflow chat works? I can't find it

Comment: I just sent you an email (which includes information on how I found your email address which I won't repeat here).

Comment: it's chat.stackoverflow.com - there are no private chats, just general public chat rooms